# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am developing an application in asp.net MVC 2.0 in which I am calling the function of `Repository` in controller but it is giving me an exception of `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` and Its not allowing me to debug this line so I am unable to find the Problem. Here is the code.

```
private IIssueRepository _issueRepository;

public double CalculateLoadBar(long userID)
{
    int i = 0;
    double load = 0;
    var issues = _issueRepository.GetAssignedIssues(userID);
}
```

Please tell me how to trace out the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you posted, it appears that `_issueRepository` is not set to an object - it is not instantiated anywhere.

It needs to be instantiated before you can call methods on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try instantiate this object before use it like following :

```
_issueRepository = new IssueRepository();
```

hope this help.

Comment: Or use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).